# create chart with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, charts

hi I'm trying to create a chart with php and mysql to show daily number of posts that generate **Automatically** using mysql queries.in database just we have date column.

I want some thing like this

```
  date      |  posts count
------------+---------------
2017/05/02  |    5
2017/05/03  |    0
2017/05/04  |    1 
2017/05/05  |    2
2017/05/06  |    0
2017/05/07  |    3
```

how to do this?

Comment: Go read up on COUNT and GROUP BY ...

Comment: @CBroe we wrote query with count and group by but that can not calculate 0 for days we do not have any post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by day and still show days without rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902297/group-by-day-and-still-show-days-without-rows)

Comment: thanks I see that but The answers are wrong and that queries Do not display 0 in a row

Comment: And how exactly are those answers “wrong” please? That they will need some adapting to fit your specific case is obvious, sure. But if you consider them _wrong_, then please explain why exactly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to learn how to use these two:

[Group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

[COUNT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html)

---

Since I have no idea about your table architecture here is a sample that you can adjust to your case:

```
select p.datePost, count(p.id) as postcounts
  from posts p
  group by p.datePost
```

Comment: we wrote this query:`SELECT post.post_date,COUNT(*) as postTime
        FROM  post
        WHERE post.post_is_active = 1
        GROUP BY DAY( ADDDATE( post.post_date , DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) ) )ORDER BY post.post_date DESC` but this can not calculate the days we do not have a post